# Finding counter part records in an excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I just wanted to create a plain macro which will do the following:

[image: image1]

It just checks in a different data set if there is a counterpart record.
First it checks if it finds the same amount and if so it checks the date and text. If everything is identical it should highlight the record.
I’m new to this, so I tried in the first step just to check for the right amount and highlight the cell, but even this not really works :(. I just tried it with a double loop, here is the code:

```
Dim row1 As Integer
Dim row2 As Integer
Dim index1 As Integer
Dim index2 As Integer

index1 = 0
index2 = 0
row1 = 2
row2 = 10

Do
 Do
    If Cells(row1, 1).Value = Cells(row2, 13).Value Then
    Cells(row1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Exit Do
    End If
    row2 = row2 + 1
   index2 = index2 + 1
  Loop Until index2 = 12

    index1 = index1 + 1
    row1 = row1 + 1
Loop Until index1 = 5
```

Later I also want to include a function to count the rows, so that this macro also works if the number of rows will change.

Excel macro extension:

[image: Screenshot for extension]

Comment: Well column 13 is column M, did you mean to have that as `Cell(row2, 13).Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to test against multiple criteria, you'll want to use `And` and change the column positioning in the `Cells` statement each time.

Also you need to reset `index2` to 0 after your second `Do` loop, otherwise it will move beyond 12 and never meet your exit criteria of `Loop Until index2 = 12`, resulting in an `Overflow`.

To highlight the whole row (and not just column A, you'll need to use `Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x, y))` to indicate that range.

Lastly, you need to have your first loops exit criteria be `Loop Until index1 = 4`, because since you initialize `index1` as 0, 5 iterations is the equivalency of 0 to 4, not 0 to 5.

(Also, I left your variables alone, but take note that best practice when declaring variables used in `Loop`s is to declare them as `Long`s, not `Integer`s. Integers max out around ~32,000 rows, where `Long`s can exceed a million.)

```
Sub Test()
Dim row1 As Integer
Dim row2 As Integer
Dim index1 As Integer
Dim index2 As Integer

index1 = 0
index2 = 0
row1 = 2
row2 = 10

Do
    Do
        If Cells(row1, 1).Value = Cells(row2, 1).Value And _
           Cells(row1, 3).Value = Cells(row2, 3).Value Then
            If Cells(row1, 2).Value <> Cells(row2, 2).Value Then
                Range(Cells(row1, 1), Cells(row1, 3)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Range(Cells(row1, 2), Cells(row1, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Range(Cells(row2, 1), Cells(row2, 3)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Range(Cells(row2, 2), Cells(row2, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Else
                Range(Cells(row1, 1), Cells(row1, 3)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Range(Cells(row2, 1), Cells(row2, 3)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If

        row2 = row2 + 1
        index2 = index2 + 1

    Loop Until index2 = 12

    row1 = row1 + 1
    index1 = index1 + 1
    index2 = 0
    row2 = 10

Loop Until index1 = 4

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Wow, thanks dwirony for this great answer! Would it be also possible to check Date and Text step by step? So that amount would be checked first, if the amount matches the macro checks the Date, if the Date doesn't match it would be colored yellow, next it would check Text, if text is the same it would be colored red and if Date and Text doesn't match nothing would be colored (also not the amount)? If this would be just a quick thing for you, it would be great if you could help me, else I will try it on my own, but I think I can't do it in a efficient way ;)

Comment: @Dupor What if the date and text both match?

Comment: In this case Amount Date Text will be red. Everything with a match will be red everthing what doesn't match will be yellow BUT if Amount is no match nothing will be colored.

Comment: @Dupor I would need an updated picture from you of your **expected result**. The picture you posted above does not mirror the criteria you're writing now - I would expect the second `13` amount line to be yellow, since it has a matching amount line above without a matching date.

Comment: @Dupor Be advised, I added another line to the code (`row2 = 10`). This was missing some iterations for some of your rows. This will grab everything.